# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

public class Kata
{
   public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
   {
        TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        string clearStr = Regex.Replace(myTI.ToTitleCase(str), @"_|-", "");
        return clearStr = str.Substring(0, 3) + clearStr.Remove(0, 3);     
   }
}
```

input - > ToCamelCase("the_stealth_warrior")

input - > ToCamelCase("The-Stealth-Warrior")

> Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Index and length must
>   refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whay is the desired output for `"a"`, `"ab"`?

Comment: I have just tried your code. It runs without throwing an exception on my machine. Are you sure you did not have passed same other values, like String.Empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the exception thrown at `Substring(0, 3)` or `Remove(0, 3)` in case either `str` or `clearStr` is shorter than `3`. I suggest adding validation:

```
public static string ToCamelCase(string str) {
  // if str is null or too short 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    return str;
  else if (str.Length < 3)
    return str;

  TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
  string clearStr = Regex.Replace(myTI.ToTitleCase(str), @"_|-", "");

  // if clearStr is too short
  if (clearStr.Length < 3)
    return str;

  return clearStr = str.Substring(0, 3) + clearStr.Remove(0, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `str` and `clearStr` length.  `Substring` will throw this error if the strings lengths are less than what you're selecting/removing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw this exception if you pass a string as `str` parameter that is shorter than 3 characters. I suggest to add a check for this in the beginning and define what the desired result is for these kind of values.